# Hibernate + SQLite do not create tables

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, netbeans

I need SQLite database in my project, but SQL is not as handy as HQL. So we have Hibernate with SQLite.
Project is being made in NetBeans 8.2, my OS is Ubuntu 17.10.

So for example we have this mini-project for testing

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:stuff.db</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">com.enigmabridge.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping resource="stuff/Stuff.hbm.xml"/>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My class called Stuff:

```
package stuff;

public class Stuff {
    private Integer id;
    private String stuff;

    public Stuff() {
    }

    public Stuff(String stuff) {
        this.stuff = stuff;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStuff() {
        return stuff;
    }

    public void setStuff(String stuff) {
        this.stuff = stuff;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Stuff{" + "id=" + id + ", stuff=" + stuff + '}';
    }

}
```

Mapping file

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="stuff.Stuff" table="stuff">
      <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
          <generator class="increment"/>
      </id>
      <property name="stuff" type="string" column="stuff"/>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And the main code

```
package stuff;

import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(new Stuff("blah blah"));

        //Query q = s.createQuery("select from Stuff");
        //List<Stuff> l = q.list();
        //for (Stuff s:l)System.out.println(s);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Data base was created via Services tab in NetBeans. Its name is stuff.db.

I use Hibernate 4.3 (JPA 2.1)

Hibernate 4 SQLite dialect was taken from here: [link](https://github.com/EnigmaBridge/hibernate4-sqlite-dialect)

Session opens and closes just fine, database file is automatically created in my home folder. But for some reason table just isn't created, I really dunno why.

Answer (score 0):

pom: SQLite JDBC library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

in hibernate config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:mydb.db</property>
        <property name="connection.username"></property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <mapping class="your mapping class"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: what is this "pom" and should I do with it?

Comment: pom is part of maven, maven is a dependency management tool, if you are not using maven you need to add a jar of it , you can download jar from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.7.2

Comment: are newer versions of sqlite drivers better than older ones?

Comment: Yes you can use newer version

Comment: I have github account but I don't use it. I can share my project from my google disk, will that do?

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1974dJRc7oExbYRVl3AnfIGYMyC56TaiV)

Comment: @IvanPopov you also need sqlite-dialect, you need download https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.kemitix/sqlite-dialect/0.1.0

Comment: also there is no log show for create table but your logic work for me   Query q = s.createQuery("from MiniStuff");
        List<MiniStuff> l = q.list();
        for (MiniStuff m:l)System.out.println(m.getId());

Comment: Actualy I have sqlite dialect in my project, it's in lib folder

Comment: I have sent you working project, i have using maven for dependency management